# SwipeRow Override on the internal button

Tags: react-native, swipe-gesture

The swipe list component works well , but there's a trick with me

There's a SwipeRow element override on a button (check the inspector details on the below screenshot)

I don't use these hidden items and so on..

instead , I wrote some customized stylings to increase the main component width and so on..

here's my codes

```js
   renderItem(item)
   {
        return (<TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection:"row"}}>
        <WideProduct increaseItemAmount={this.increaseItemAmount} decreaseItemAmount={this.decreaseItemAmount} item={item} />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
          alert("Clicking !!"); // not working
        }} style={{width:responsiveWidth(85),marginTop:responsiveHeight(19),alignItems:"center",justifyContent:"center",height:responsiveHeight(85)
        ,backgroundColor:DynamicAppStyles.colorSet.light.red}}>
                 <AntIcon color="#FFF" size={32} name="delete" />
               </TouchableOpacity>
        </TouchableOpacity>)
   }
```

**Screenshot**

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2767001/96572992-d240f480-12cd-11eb-82a7-8fed4aa6a536.jpeg

**Environment**

- OS: Android
- RN SwipeListView Version: 3.2.4
- RN Version: 61.4

here's the link for the plugin I use : https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view

if this issue has no solution , please recommend a better library or how to make it without (plugins/libraries)